# What does a small arrow next to a cursor mean?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, selections

I'm wondering what this cursor means. The left arrow appears when you hold CTRL/CMD + Left Click on any fill.

[image]

Comment: Not sure but my guess would be to indicate the the selection tool can act like the direct select tool or anchor point tool when you CTRL/CMD + Left Click a fill.

Comment: Cursor is smaller than... (life?)

Comment: If you have more than one object under your cursor, this will select the next object under the current selection. If the bottom-most object is selected, it cycles back to the top.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know about that! You should post that as an answer @FirstDraft

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you happen to have a source for that or did you discover it by yourself? @FirstDraft

Comment: @XETU You can see an explanation in the Illustrator docs here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-objects.html#select_behind_objects

Comment: @CaiMorris Thanks. They should've added the cursor picture, though.

Comment: @XETU I Agree. I read that exact page looking to answer this question and still didn't know what it was till FirstDraft said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have more than one object under your cursor, this will select the next object under the current selection. If the bottom-most object is selected, it cycles back to the top.